# XL6009 voltage booster damaging Arduino Uno from Vin pin

Tags: arduino, power, current

I used two Li-ion batteries (3.7 volts, 1300 mAh) connected in parallel, charged by a solar panel, connected to a charging module (TP4056) and attached the load of TP4056 to the voltage booster module XL6009.

I adjusted the output voltage in the booster to be 8 volts. I then attached a fuse (1A) from the +Ve voltage out to Arduino Vin pin and connected common grounds. I attached one servo motor (MG90S) and a stepper (28BYJ-48) to the Arduino; both motors are 5V.

I uploaded the code and everything was working fine. I then removed the USB and connected power through the Vin pin. When I connected the Vin pin, the components did not work while Arduino is on and LED is on. Afterwards the Arduino was not recognized by the laptop and does not want to restart (the old code keeps running but the Arduino is not recognized by laptop). This happened on two Arduino boards. Are they both fried and what did I do wrong?

Comment: Welcome! Please post a schematic or block diagram of how everything is connected.

Comment: Ok I will draw it and upload it